# Eclipse : Error: Could not find or load main class Original

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-18.04

I want to run a project(in eclipse). On running I get the following(snapshot) error. I have read about how eclipse has problems finding path and have tried a few things but I am still stuck after spending my whole day in this. The file I am looking at has Main class and main function inside it and I could not find class 'Original' in any file(2k+). I had a new installation java and eclipse, if that matters. Any pointers would be really helpful.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, select pull-down menu `Run` > `Run Configurations...`.

In the `Run Configurations.` dialog, locate nodes nested below the `Java Application` node. Select them one at a time, and click the red `X` to delete them. Then close the dialog.

In the `Package Explorer` view on the left that shows your project and Java files, select the `Main` class. Right-click the class and select `Run As` -> `Java Application`.

Comment: I have to use '-Djava.library.path=....' in run configurations argument. When I do what you said above without run configuration I get a new error which says 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: Properties file 'cdgclient/postgres.properties' not found in the classpath'. 

If I add the run configuration, then I get the old error.

Comment: The run configuration is where the class name to run is specified, so if it is trying to run class `Original`, then the run configuration is saying that. Fix the run configuration. --- If you had followed my instructions, then `Run As` -> `Java Application` would have created a new run configuration for the `Main` class, and you wouldn't have any run configurations naming the `Original` class.

Comment: Since `java.library.path` has nothing to do with the `classpath`, I'm confused as to why not specifying that system property would show error about classpath.

Comment: r1: When I add the library path(which has many jar files), could the order in which the jars are referenced be an issue?
r2: Maybe when I specify the library path, the error is caught there first. Does it make sense?

Comment: The library path has *nothing* to do with loading `.jar` files. It is used for loading `.so` files (or `.dll` files on Windows). See e.g. [What is the relation between java.library.path and classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24964012/5221149)

Comment: Okay, my bad, I am new to eclipse and Java. I have two .so files in the library path, again, is there a reference order among them?

Comment: No, there is no order. If the library path lists more than one directory, they will or course be searched in the order listed.